# Phone number shown as unknown. Always says sender is invalid

Tags: caller-id

I have a Samsung Galaxy S SHW-M1105 and it displays my phone number as unknown. Is there a way to change it? And one more when I try to reply a message it says the sender is invalid. Someone please help

Answer (score 1):

You can enable your caller ID from `Settings` -> `Call settings` -> `All calls` -> `Show my number` -> `Show`. As for the SMS reply problem, please check the settings in your Messaging app, make sure that the `SMSC` (Short Message Service Center) number is correct foryour network and `SMS Reply Path` is off. Otherwise, just double-check the number and try with and without the international format.