# Phone number shown as unknown in galaxy tab

Tags: settings, privacy

I have a samsung galaxy tab 2 gt-p3100. My problem is somewhat similar to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/26090/16220) issue, but I notice this when I go into my settings: Settings > About Device > Status > My phone number ... it is listed as unknown phone number.

Question is how to set the phone number for my device so that it shows up in the above mentioned path.

Comment: The question you linked to is a phone, how would the Galaxy Tab 2 have a phone number? does this device even have a phone radio?

Comment: Its has call facility,  and the 3g too...

Answer (score 0):

Well @RyanConrad yes this device supports voice and video calling I have been using tab2 from a while but like OP said the number doesn't appear over my device too. So, I would say this might be happening because our service provider doesn't supports this service and you can't manually set the phone number over their !